# Routes disappearing from OSPF routing table

Tags: ospf

For some reason I am seeing OSPF routes being removed from its routing table every 3-4 hours, yet they are still in the database. When this happens, there is still a neighbor relationship between the 2 routers.

What could be the possible reason for this and how can it be fixed/prevented?  If you need some output from anything, let me know.

Comment: What make/model are the routers?

Comment: Also, how are the (OSPF propagated) routes sourced originally? Maybe you could give a hint about the topology of the network?

Comment: Data is indeed quite thin to make heads or tails. Is this flat, single process area0? Database dump of routes during and after issue would be sufficient. How do you recover from it, or does the issue resolve itself, how long does it take to resolve? If I'd have to stab in the dark, I'd guess you have some link flapping somewhere causing rerouting and backup path has max-metric (kinda like ISIS overload)

Comment: Downvoting this question since it's missing quite a lot of information that would be useful (and would likely lead to more answers!), but the core question itself is good.

Comment: To follow-up a bit.  Once I redistributed connected routes into OSPf, things have been stable since.  Thanks for the comments.

Comment: @NetworkNinja, please add an answer to the bottom of this question with your solution and accept it, so the system won't keep bumping the question from time to time.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

For cisco routers, there's a KB article about it:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk365technologies_tech_note09186a008009481a.shtml

From the article:

> A common problem when using Open Shortest Path First (OSPF) is routes in the 
>   database don't appear in the routing table. In most cases OSPF finds a 
>   discrepancy in the database so it doesn't install the route in the routing
>   table. Often, you can see the Adv Router is not-reachable message (which means
>   that the router advertising the LSA is not reachable through OSPF) on top of
>   the link-state advertisement (LSA) in the database when this problem occurs.

So I guess that the issue has to do with the advertising router becoming unreachable periodically, but the question has too little info to make a guess about the root cause...

Comment: Hi Aziraphale, we generally like to see answers contain stand-alone information, rather than relying wholly on links. Can you edit your answer to at-least summarize the information in the KB you've linked to?